# pyQT phonon player to fullscreen?

Tags: python, pyqt, fullscreen, phonon

i was wondering how to set a phonon player to full screen?
im trying this codes.

```
    if not self.ui.videoPlayer.isFullScreen():
        self.ui.videoPlayer.enterFullScreen()
    else: 
        self.ui.videoPlayer.exitFullScreen()
```

but i keep on getting this error message

> TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable

the code above works is from a sample project. the original code was

```
def full(self):
    if not self.videoWidget.isFullScreen():
        self.videoWidget.enterFullScreen()
    else: 
        self.videoWidget.exitFullScreen()
```

im recreating it in PyQT and it seems hard for me.
can anyone please guide me on what im missing(having a hunch about it)
or what im doing wrong?

Comment: This may not be helpful, but if you use Wing IDE or Pycharm you can easily debug and see the exact line and issue and what object is causing it using the debugger and interactive console. Usually solves this category of problem implicitly for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [VideoPlayer](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-videoplayer.html) is not the same thing as a [VideoWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-videowidget.html).

`VideoPlayer` is a subclass of `QWidget`, so it *will* have an `isFullScreen` method - but it *won't* have the methods `enterFullScreen` and `exitFullScreen`, which belong to the `VideoWidget` class.

However, the `VideoPlayer` class has a [videoWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-videoplayer.html#videoWidgetx) method which returns the instance of the video widget it uses, so your code example should probably be changed to:

```
videoWidget = self.ui.videoPlayer.videoWidget()
if videoWidget.isFullScreen():
    videoWidget.exitFullScreen()
else: 
    videoWidget.enterFullScreen()
```

**EDIT**

To provide a method for exiting fullscreen mode, set up a keyboard shortcut:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self)
        ...
        self.shortcutFull = QtGui.QShortcut(self)
        self.shortcutFull.setKey(QtGui.QKeySequence('F11'))
        self.shortcutFull.setContext(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
        self.shortcutFull.activated.connect(self.handleFullScreen)

    def handleFullScreen(self):
        videoWidget = self.ui.videoPlayer.videoWidget()
        if videoWidget.isFullScreen():
            videoWidget.exitFullScreen()
        else: 
            videoWidget.enterFullScreen()
```

Comment: this is great. it definitely works! thanks ekhumoro. just a follow up question. i manage to made it on fullscreen mode. have any tip on how i can exit it? since its on fullscreen. i cant push the button activating the fullscreen mode... again thanks!

Comment: @Katherina. See my updated answer for a way to exit fullscreen mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed sample you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your use of `self.ui.videoPlayer.isFullScreen`, it's probably returning True or False, which when you use `self.ui.videoPlayer.isFullScreen()` is really resolving down to 'False()'.

Oddly enough, the PyQT [documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/phonon-videowidget.html) doesn't even list 'isFullScreen' as part of the available, methods/properties. However the [QWidget documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#fullScreen-prop) does show isFullScreen as returning a boolean.

Instead, try this:

```
if not self.ui.videoPlayer.isFullScreen:
    self.ui.videoPlayer.enterFullScreen()
else: 
    self.ui.videoPlayer.exitFullScreen()
```

Comment: hi there i tried your given answer..i got an error ""    self.ui.videoPlayer.exitFullScreen()
TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable. im still trying to fix this synthesizerpatel